# passing std::plus<>() as a predicate

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I need to pass `std::plus<>()` as a predicate to a function that does something similar to accumulate, but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this. The template argument I want to pass `std::plus` into is:

```
Pred && op
```

and when I try to use std::plus as `op`:

```
return detail::reduce(..., std::plus<>()); //.... op = std::plus<>()
```

but this does not work, I get the error `error C2976: 'std::plus' : too few template arguments` which I should have seen coming, but I don't know how to work around this and pass plus correctly.

One context in which I'm using op:

```
std::accumulate(first, last, std::forward<T>(init),
                        std::forward<Pred>(op)));
```

one such overload of `detail::reduce`:

```
template <typename ExPolicy, typename InIter, typename T, typename Pred>
typename detail::algorithm_result<ExPolicy, T>::type
reduce_seq(ExPolicy const&, InIter first, InIter last, T && init,
    Pred && op)
{
    try {
        return detail::algorithm_result<ExPolicy, T>::get(
            std::accumulate(first, last, std::forward<T>(init),
                std::forward<Pred>(op)));
    }
    catch(std::bad_alloc const& e) {
        boost::throw_exception(e);
    }
    catch (...) {
        boost::throw_exception(
            hpx::exception_list(boost::current_exception())
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware, in C++14 your construction will work and take on a new meaning.

Comment: Try specifying the template parameter, *i.e.*, `std::plus<T>()`.

Comment: @Syntactic Fructose can you add the definition of the `detail::reduce` function? i want to reply with the solution based on your function

Comment: @Raxvan The detail::reduce consists of many overloaded functions, but i'll post just one of them (this is the `n3960` proposal implementation), if you just want to specify how to pass it either way it would answer the question.

Comment: @KerrekSB due to what ? can you be more specific ?

Comment: `std::plus<>()` should work on VS2013, it implements the C++14 change where the template argument to `operator()` is deduced. On earlier versions you'll have to specify the argument explicitly - `std::plus<T>()`

Comment: @user2485710: Search for "transparent comparators" and "diamond predicates".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to specify the predicate as a function argument you must provide a type for `std::plus` like in this context:

```
some_function(std::plus<T>());
```

However you can make it a template argument directly: like so:

```
template < template < class > class PRED, class T >
T foo(T a,T b)
{
    return PRED<T>()(a,b);
}
int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    foo<std::plus>(a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

For your case i think this would work:

```
template <template <typename> typename Pred, typename ExPolicy, typename InIter, typename T >
typename detail::algorithm_result<ExPolicy, T>::type reduce_seq(ExPolicy const&, InIter first, InIter last, T && init)
{
   stuff = Pred<T>()(some_value,other_value);
}

//usage:
reduce_seq<std::plus>(arguments...);
```

Comment: In C++14 the built-in functor templates such as `std::plus` do not require a type. You can use `std::plus<>()` and it will work with any type: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3421.htm